# Positioning Two Nav Elements in Subheader

Tags: css

I need some help positioning two nav elements (2 and 3) in a subheader (1).  Please, refer to the mockup.

[image]

I am really only concerned with positioning here. I want to position the daysNav (2) on the left, and opposite it, the paginationNav (3) on the right.  It would also be cool if I didn't have to define a fixed height for the subheader both elements are in; instead, it'd expand and collapse automatically based on the largest height size of either element.

Thanks!

Comment: post the code in your question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #subhead {overflow:hidden;}
.days-nav {float:left;}
.pagination-nav {float:right;}

<div id="subhead">

    <div class="days-nav">
        ....
    </div>

    <div class="pagination-nav">
        ....
    </div>

</div>
```